# How can I import static file to populate message in controller?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel API project where I want to hardcode response messages and reuse them in any controller, How can I achieve this?

I have created response.php under `APP\Traits\`  folder which has below code:

```
<php 
    return = [ 'success' => 'Response successfull!!!', 'error' => 'Error Authenticating']
?>
```

In my controller I tried to import via the construct function, its now working:

```
    use App\Traits\response;
    public function __construct( response $response) {
        $this->response = $respose;
    }

$this->response->success;  // outputs message
```

Please help me. I wanted to understand how do we import such files, JSONs or any other utility function to reuse?

Comment: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ | https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using *config* (common method)

in (in `config/response.php`)

```
return [
    'success' => 'Response successful!!!',
    'error' => 'Error Authenticating',
];
```

So in the code, you can use

```
config('response.success');
Config::get('response.success'); // with config facades
```

---

### Using *Traits*

in `App\Traits`

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait ResponseMsg
{
    public function successMessage()
    {
        return 'Response successful!!!';
    }

    public function errorMessage()
    {
        return 'Error Authenticating';
    }
}
```

In code

```
 use ResponseMsg;
 $this->successMessage();
```